# Making several models(trying various parameters) without for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, purrr

I'm trying to test my model, and previously I used for-loops to change parameters of my model like-

```
assessment <- c()
for(para1 in 1:10){
    for(para2 in 1:10){
        fit <- model(data, para1, para2)
        assessment <- c(assessment, model_score(fit))
    }
}
```

I used support vector machine(svm function) and AUC to test my model.
Each for loop takes about 20 to 30 seconds.

I have two questions to ask-

- Is there any benefit to not using for-loop in this case?

I vaguely recognize I should avoid for-loop in R programming, but I am not sure if avoiding for-loop will improve the performance significantly here.

- If that's the case, how should I avoid for-loop?

I think using 'purrr' package would be necessary here, but I can't quite figure out how I should apply it to my case.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check out ```caret``` library.

Comment: One non-`for`-loop option would be to use `sapply` to make a vector of formulae for all the models you'd like to test (with `paste` and `as.formula` as the workhorses in the function used in `sapply`), then use `lapply` to iterate your model-testing function over all the elements of the resulting vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid growing objects in a loop with `c()`. Instead, consider using an apply family function. One way is to use `expand.grid` to build a data frame of all possible combinations of both parameters and then pass column values elementwise into your model with `mapply` (or its non-simplified wrapper `Map`).

```
proc_model <- function(p1, p2) {
  fit <- model(data, p1, p2)
  return(model_score(fit))
}

param_pairs <- expand.grid(para1 = 1:10, para2 = 1:10)

# VECTOR/MATRIX OUTPUT
assessment <- mapply(proc_model, param_pairs$para1, param_pairs$para2)

# LIST OUTPUT
assessment <- Map(proc_model, param_pairs$para1, param_pairs$para2)
```

Comment: It is indeed better than a simple loop. Thanks!